# Jenkins failed with error: Test reports were found but none of them are new. Did leafNodes run?

Tags: jenkins, junit

I have provided an empty xml report file in the Jenkins workspace and typed its relative path in the `Test report XMLs` field in the configure page. But now I get this error and I don't know what it is.

Comment: I am facing same issue. Is this resolved?

Comment: I am having the same issue. Need support.